# How to use compojure from Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, ring, compojure

I've spent more time that I want to admit trying to compile and run a compojure app from intellij. From the command line I use lein ring server-headless. If I run from inside intellij the REPL begins and I can't call or start the server from inside the REPL. How can I compile and run a server from inside the REPL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to run the server from inside the repl?

Add `[ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.3.1"]` as a dependency

In the REPL:

`(require 'ring.adapter.jetty)`

`(require 'quals.core.handler)` ; require **YOUR** ns containing the handler

`(ring.adapter.jetty/run-jetty quals.core.handler/app {:port 3004})`

You can see all the parameters you can pass here:
http://mmcgrana.github.io/ring/ring.adapter.jetty.html

There you have it, the server is running in your repl. If you were looking for more, you can always look at [weavejester/lein-ring](https://github.com/weavejester/lein-ring)'s source code.

Have fun Clojuring around :)

Comment: If you're using http-kit does that mean you are no longer using ring and therefore the above won't work? Or does compojure still use ring under the hood?

Comment: Compojure simply builds a handler that ring or http-kit can use!
It's actually there to make building complex handlers easier.

Comment: If you want to start a server from the REPL using http-kit you just have to follow this http://www.http-kit.org/server.html#stop-server.
You just have to pass it the handler (that you made with Compojure).